# simplexml_load_file cannot display content that has colon ":"

Tags: php, scripting, rss, simplexml

I am using simplexml_load_file to extract-->display an RSS feed.

I am having trouble in particular with displaying a value that contains a colon.

For example:

Any ideas how I can display clicked-tcount and comment-counts?

My php loop is:

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
if ($i < 1000)  { // parse only 10 items
    print $item->title.'<br>'.$item->ddescription.' ' .$item->pubDate.'<br /><br><br><BR>';
}

$i++;
}
```

Comment: uh, well, xml example?

Comment: Sorry! I thought I included that...

Comment: The term you're looking for to search on is "namespace". There are several good answers on how to deal with them via SimpleXML - I've linked one to the top of your question.

Comment: <site:meta comment-counts="15" link="www." clicked-tcount="11"/>

Comment: Using the `children('site', true)` method to search child nodes in the `site` namespace.